# How to unpack the group_by() do() output from dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following code that performs the `summary()` for the `iris$Petal.Width` grouped by species

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- iris %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  select(Petal.Width, Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  do(fn = summary(.$Petal.Width))


dat
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Species    fn                  
#> * <fct>      <list>              
#> 1 setosa     <S3: summaryDefault>
#> 2 versicolor <S3: summaryDefault>
#> 3 virginica  <S3: summaryDefault>
```

What I want to do is to unpack the `fn` column into the following ( I do this by hand)

```r
Species     Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
setosa      0.100   0.200   0.200   0.246   0.300   0.600 
versicolor  1.000   1.200   1.300   1.326   1.500   1.800  
virginica   1.400   1.800   2.000   2.026   2.300   2.500
```

How can I do it?

I tried this but failed `dat %>% ungroup(fn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently, explicit list columns are preferred as an idiom over `do`. In this case, it might look like

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(summary = list(broom::tidy(summary(Petal.Width)))) %>% 
    unnest()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   Species    minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum
#>   <fct>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 setosa       0.100 0.200  0.200 0.246 0.300   0.600
#> 2 versicolor   1.00  1.20   1.30  1.33  1.50    1.80 
#> 3 virginica    1.40  1.80   2.00  2.03  2.30    2.50
```

If you like, this is one of those cases where the base R idiom is more concise and readable:

```r
aggregate(Petal.Width ~ Species, iris, summary)
#>      Species Petal.Width.Min. Petal.Width.1st Qu. Petal.Width.Median
#> 1     setosa            0.100               0.200              0.200
#> 2 versicolor            1.000               1.200              1.300
#> 3  virginica            1.400               1.800              2.000
#>   Petal.Width.Mean Petal.Width.3rd Qu. Petal.Width.Max.
#> 1            0.246               0.300            0.600
#> 2            1.326               1.500            1.800
#> 3            2.026               2.300            2.500
```

However, note that if you call `str` on the result, it shows `Petal.Width` is actually a matrix column (which isn't possible in tibbles, but is in data.frames). To extract it, tack on `%>% {cbind(.[1], .[[2]])}` or equivalent.

`skimr::skim` is another option which respects dplyr grouping:

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% skimr::skim(Petal.Width)
#> Skim summary statistics
#>  n obs: 150 
#>  n variables: 5 
#>  group variables: Species 
#> 
#> Variable type: numeric 
#>     Species    variable missing complete  n mean   sd  p0 p25 p50 p75 p100
#>      setosa Petal.Width       0       50 50 0.25 0.11 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3  0.6
#>  versicolor Petal.Width       0       50 50 1.33 0.2  1   1.2 1.3 1.5  1.8
#>   virginica Petal.Width       0       50 50 2.03 0.27 1.4 1.8 2   2.3  2.5
#>      hist
#>  ▂▇▁▂▂▁▁▁
#>  ▆▃▇▅▆▂▁▁
#>  ▂▁▇▃▃▆▅▃
```

What it displays is actually a print method for underlying long data. skimr is built to keep working with dplyr methods, but at some point you may need to hack the underlying data out. The documentation explains pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
dat <- iris %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  select(Petal.Width, Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  do(fn = summary(.$Petal.Width)  %>% as.matrix() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame())

dat %>% unnest()

# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#   Species     Min. `1st Qu.` Median  Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max.
#   <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 setosa     0.100     0.200  0.200 0.246     0.300 0.600
# 2 versicolor 1.00      1.20   1.30  1.33      1.50  1.80 
# 3 virginica  1.40      1.80   2.00  2.03      2.30  2.50
```